# Change datepicker date format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers, the minDate from the second datepicker is the date from the first datepicker. 
The problem is that if i want to change the value from 'mm/dd/yy' to 'dd-mm-yy' in the dateFormat variable, the second datepicker loses the minDate. 
I want in both datepickers the date format to be 'dd-mm-yy'.

```js
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = 'mm/dd/yy',
    from = $("#from")
    .datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      numberOfMonths: 2
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      numberOfMonths: 2
    })

  function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }

    return date;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="from" />
<input id="to" />
```

Comment: Seems like it's working for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provided you're not using the same date format everywhere.

```
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = 'dd-mm-yy',
    from = $("#from")
    .datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: dateFormat,
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
      dateFormat: dateFormat,
      numberOfMonths: 2
    })

  function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }

    return date;
  }
});
```

here I provide the variable dateFormat to the datepickers which fixes it.